# How to see the content of keystore in Android simulator

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to store sensitive information in the users' device. I want to see if this is stored properly in Android Keystore, but I don't know how.

I could use SQLite Browser to see the data in keychain of my iOS simulator using its device ID, but I don't know where the data is for my Android simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This package probably stores them inside **SharedPreferences**. You can use Android Studio to open the relevant XML file (that's how they are stored).

Open Android Studio and [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html). Then, please find:

> /data/data/[package name/shared_prefs

You can browse the file and check if the values that you needed to store are inside.